# Flask Python - Put request returns only 404 after changing host to 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, rest, network-programming, python-requests

After setting the .py script to have `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` all my put/get/etc request end up in 404.

> E:\location>c:Python27\python.exe coordinatorSim.py
>   * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   192.168.0.101 - - [01/Nov/2015 09:19:18] "PUT /patient/start HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I send the request to `192.168.0.103:5000/patient/start` from another machine in the wifi network, which is the ip of the machine on which the py script runs on.

If I remove the `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`, than the requests work, on the default localhost address, `127.0.0.1:5000` (given that I send the request to `127.0.0.103:5000/patient/start`)

What is it that I am missing?

the put request is:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
sSocket = None
......
    # Creates client for socket communication. The http client supplies the IP address and port no.
@app.route('/patient/start', methods = ['PUT'])
#@requires_auth
def patient_start():
    global sThreadStarted
    global sSocket
    global sSocketThread
    # If the client is already started, return an error code !?
    #print "JSON:", request.json

    if len(request.json) > 0:

        l_address = request.json["address"]
        l_port = request.json["port"]
        # Start client
        print l_address, l_port
        try:

            sSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error, e:
            return "Error creating socket: " + e
        try:

            sSocket.connect((l_address, int(l_port)))
        except socket.gaierror, e:
            return "Address error: " + e
        except socket.error, e:
            return "Connection error: " + e

        try:
            sThreadStarted = True
            sSocketThread.start()
        except threading.ThreadError, e:
            return "Threading error: " + e

        message = {
                'status': 200,
                'message': 'Socket created'
            }
        resp = jsonify(message)
        resp.status_code = 200

        return resp
    else:
        return bad_request()
```

Comment: I don't think you can run on 0.0.0.0 without `DEBUG` [disabled](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/)

Comment: @jvc26 Actually **never** run on `0.0.0.0` with `debug` mode is a good idea, but I think that isn't the problem.

Comment: Heh, yes indeed - I don't actually think Flask lets you, but you're right, that would be daft!

Comment: just set `app.debug = True`, but there is no change in the outcome

Comment: what is `bad_request` there ?Also check localhost:5000 even app start in 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Ale My answer will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue while hosting my Flask React App on Amazon EC2. Took me a couple of hours to resolve this issue.

The solution is to set the `SERVER_NAME = None` in the settings.py file for the Flask App.

All credits to [Ronhanson](https://github.com/ronhanson) for his comment on [Github](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/113).

Just to reiterate :

1. Open port `5000` in the EC2 security group inbound rules.
2. In manage.py add the line `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`
3. In settings.py update `SERVER_NAME = None`

Follow the above steps and your app would be accessible from external networks.

Answer (score 1):

From doc

> > By default, a route only answers to GET requests, but that can be changed by providing the methods argument to the route() decorator

So you have to set

```
@app.route('/url', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
```

Comment: i do have `@app.route('/patient/start', methods = ['PUT'])` in my script, but the outcome is still a 404..

Comment: is 404 when run in `0.0.0.0` only?

Comment: yes. on `0.0.0.0`, and the request is send to  `192.168.0.103:5000/patient/start`  from my android phone which has the ip `192.168.0.101`

Comment: Please post your code(that route), so we can find if any decorators or something there.

Comment: what is bad_request there ?Also check localhost:5000 even app start in 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem in a small Raspberry Pi script, I found that having the "app.run(host='0.0.0.0')" at the top of the script was a problem.

I now use a construct like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response
...
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Yadda yadda yadda!"

@app.route('/properties', methods=['GET'])
def get_properties():
    return jsonify({'site': site})
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

The "debug=True" works fine in this context, as do GETs and PUTs from remote clients. The documentation *discourages* the use of debug=True when listening on all addresses, but does not prohibit it ("If you have debug disabled *or trust* the users on your network...", emphasis mine).

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem that i couldnt run my app in local network. The error message in my web browser was

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server. If you
>   entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

and in the log of my terminal it said

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

so -> it couldnt find anything, why:

The problem is that you run your app with app.run its not a var so:
First you have to make your imports, build and configurate your app. Then you can start your web server which is running your app at your local machine like this in your

```
 __init__.py
```

`app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)`

or like this directly at the end of your web app

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```